# HighCharts pointPlacement option not working in a single column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

It looks like pointPlacement is not working with a single column...

> The point placement can also be numeric, where 0 is on the axis value,
>   -0.5 is between this value and the previous, and 0.5 is between this value and the next. Unlike the textual options, numeric point
>   placement options won't affect axis padding.

Like in the example below where i removed this data it doesn't work anymore:

```
{
  name: 'Employees Optimized',
  color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
  data: [140],
  pointPadding: 0.4,
  pointPlacement: -0.2
},{
  name: 'Profit',
  color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
  data: [183.6],
  pointPadding: .3,
  pointPlacement: 0.2,
  yAxis: 1
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointplacement-numeric/

This jsfiddle shows the usual pointplacement option. If you adjust this fiddle and remove 2 of the 3 data-sets, the pointplacement option is broken, while even in that case it should still be usefull to have and working, even required in my case...

*edit*

I added this into a fiddle because the only one responding so far didn't get the point from the code example. So here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/dargno/3YMyq/

If anyone knows a possible solution without having to "hack" the source code i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue.  I took out 3 of the series and made the pointPlacement -0.5 for the remaining series.  They are skewed to the left as I would expect. http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/tKzf5/.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing 2 out of the 3 data points in each of the series and check again :) i'll make a fiddle with the "bugged" version for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this issue myself in my particular instance by adding a negative margin to the graph area, and adding an extra (empty) data point.

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  marginRight: -400
```

And

```
series: [{
  name: 'Employees',
  color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
  data: [150,0],
```

Keep in mind the tooltips might get "lost" if you're not carefull that way though.

An example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/dargno/wtaaH/

While this is not a proper solution, it certainly circumvents the bug for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like possibly bug, so I reported to our developers here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2308